# Telnet to postfix server not working correctly

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

When running: telnet localhost 25 on a box with postfix running (verified listening on port 25) the expected behavior is:

```
[user@box ~]$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 fqdn ESMTP
```

When I telnet to my box I get the following: (postfix 2.6.6)

```
[root@host postfix]# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Postfix seems to be running

```
x]# netstat -plnt |grep :25
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      44950/master       


tfix]# ps -ef | grep post
root     44950     1  0 16:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/postfix/master
```

I am trying to verify my postfix config and it does not even seem to be running on port 25 correctly. Any assistance/suggestions greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

i hope you have set your 
inet_interfaces = all in postifx/main.cf file.

Comment: They're on localhost, so it should work even with `inet_interfaces = loopback-only`.